# Visual Studio Shortcut to Move from T-SQL Editor to Results Grid

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql, keyboard-shortcuts, resultset

I'm using the Transact-SQL editor in Visual Studio 2012 to run queries as well build my database objects.

When you run a query, the results appear in a grid. This grid does not seem to be considered an open file nor an active tool window; rather it appears as if it's an extension to the status bar. Does this container have a name?

I find it very annoying to get there by mouse. Is there a keyboard shortcut for moving to/from the query/results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> for jumping from the query to the result grid.

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it its working for VS2012. F6 works for VS2010.

Comment: And how do you jump back to the editor? I see that after an initial `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F6`, you can toggle between editor and result grid via `Ctrl`+`-`.

Comment: http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2012/ presents you with various other shortcuts besides SQL editor shortcuts.